# simple_form checkboxes collection with "other" checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, simple-form

I use `simple_form` and have this in my form code:

```
<%= f.input :fruit, as: :check_boxes, collection: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Other'] %>
```

So I want to have a text input associated with 'Other' field next to it, so that user can click 'Other' and enter his own fruit name. How do I do it?
I tried it like `f.input(...)` as one of collection items, I've also tried adding it in `do` block, but it all seems like totally irrelevant.
How do I get the behavior I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
# view
<%= text_field_tag :alternative_fruit %>

# controller
if params[:alternative_fruit].present? && params[:your_model_name][:fruit].select(&:present?).blank?
  params[:your_model_name][:fruit] = params[:alternative_fruit]
end
```

This will overwrite the fruit name if you didn't select a checkbox with the alternative name, if you defined one.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I thought about this approach of adding different field with css customization and controller processing, but thought there would be some better approach. An option with label tied to selecting input, so that when I choose that option or click a label the input field is selected automatically. Seems like it will need quite some low-level coding to complete with CSS/JS.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it fits your question